# Detect if device is tablet

Tags: javascript

How can I detect if the device is **ONLY** tablet? This script below is not working properly.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent, tablet = /Tablet|iPad/i.test(ua);
alert("Tablet? " + tablet);
```

I don't want check if is mobile and use *else* to show tablet. I want only a function to confirm if is tablet. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Tablet as in an iPad? There are different tablets, each with different userAgents.

Comment: Someone told me that exists iPad as tablet and as mobile too

Comment: My point is that detecting an iPad is much easier compared to trying to detect all tablets in the world. Are you asking to detect only iPads, or every tablet there is?

Comment: I want detect every tablet possible.

Comment: This question is not specific enough. What have you tried that works for all tablets? The above code seems to target iPads. As for the question, I urge you to use a JavaScript library, which there are plentiful of if you Google. :) Typical Google phrase would be "Javascript detect tablets".

Comment: are you opposed to libraries?

Comment: userAgent *sniffing* is inaccurate at best

Comment: @JoeWarner Yes, I don't want libraries

Comment: So, is there no ways?

Comment: *Why* are you checking? If you're trying to work with the size of the viewport, check that. Otherwise, you're better off checking for functionality (e.g.: touch support).

Comment: @Strepk What's the question behind the question? Why do you care if it's a tablet? If it's for styling, you should just use a CSS media query to style based on the device width.

Comment: My script must work different with tablet devices, so I need check if it's

Comment: Some more ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9533106/1066234

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to just use vanilla javascript you can use the navigator API

```js
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
const isTablet = /(ipad|tablet|(android(?!.*mobile))|(windows(?!.*phone)(.*touch))|kindle|playbook|silk|(puffin(?!.*(IP|AP|WP))))/.test(userAgent);
console.log(isTablet)
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator

But I'd suggest using a library such as  wurfl.io (https://web.wurfl.io/#wurfl-js):

```
if (WURFL.is_mobile === true && WURFL.form_factor === "Tablet") {
    // targetSmartPhoneDevices();
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways to spoof user agents, like [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en) for example. `navigator.userAgent` is essentially worthless as it's untrustworthy. Better to check device width with CSS media queries for dynamic styling, or modernizr for support if using modern or experimental APIs with fallbacks for legacy browsers. And OP explicitly stated they do not want to use external libraries.

Comment: I know i'd suggest using a library but OP said he doesnt want to if you dont want to use a library and want a light solution i don't think it can get better than this?

Comment: just FYI, navigator.userAgent solution does not detect new ipad pro ;)
But for the most of the tablets forks ok for me.

Comment: Old comments, but just want to argue against @PatrickRoberts assertion that userAgent is "worthless". The fact that is can be spoofed is irrelevant. It is a way of informing which useragent I would like to be represented for. In other words, spoofing is a feature, not a bug. If a user wants to see a desktop version on a mobile, then it should be up to them. If device type trustworthiness is a problem for you, then I would suspect design flaws in your project.

Comment: @MattWay if you're checking the user agent to distinguish desktop from mobile users for styling purposes then your project is already flawed. There are CSS media queries specifically for that purpose.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree (but I don't think styling is mentioned anywhere in this thread). There are plenty of other use cases for the user agent.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts if a user wants to spoof their user agent string to break the website then you should let them and not worry about it. 99.9% of users won't do this, and the users that do do it are literally breaking their browser on purpose, so why in the world should the developer make an effort to accommodate them?.


User agent strings are completely fine to use and are a useful tool.

Comment: @ICW a better question would be why in the world a developer would make an effort to misuse an API for feature detection when there are better purpose-built APIs made available for the specific purpose of feature detection? The point is that the only valid reason to distinguish a tablet from another device is to treat it differently. Why treat it differently? Render a different UI because of screen space (again, see CSS media queries), or to enable touch events (which you should test for directly). There is no good reason to smoke test for features indirectly by checking the user agent string.

Comment: @ICW and where on earth did you come up with that statistic? I suspect it would be inappropriate for me to guess.

Comment: Hey fellas, current answer was updated in 2019 last, since that time we have news from apple, new iPadOS returns MacOS type userAgent so it won't work anymore, I think, from now we can test on touch availability only.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of working script :

```js
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function DeviceMeta() {}

DeviceMeta.prototype.name = 'DeviceMeta';

/**
 * @return {boolean}
 * @throws {Error}
 */
DeviceMeta.isMobile = function () {
    var userAgent = this.getUserAgent();

    var userAgentPart = userAgent.substr(0, 4);

    return /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(userAgent)
        || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(userAgentPart);
};

/**
 * @return {boolean}
 * @throws {Error}
 */
DeviceMeta.isMobileOrTablet = function () {
    var userAgent = this.getUserAgent();

    var userAgentPart = userAgent.substr(0, 4);

    return /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(userAgent)
        || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(userAgentPart);
};

/**
 * @return {string|null}
 * @throws {Error}
 */
DeviceMeta.getUserAgent = function () {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent
        || navigator.vendor
        || window.opera
        || null;
    
    if (!userAgent)
        throw new Error('Failed to look for user agent information.');

    return userAgent;
};
```

Comment: Any reason why you used isMobileOrTablet and not only isTablet ?

Comment: There are some differences between regular expressions for these methods.