# check if a tablet no matter the operating system of the device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if a device is a tablet to disable a certain portion of code that should only work if the device is andorid or IOS, that is, even if the table is Android or IOS if it is not a phone, that code should not be executed. Anyone have any possible solution? I read this: [What is the best way to detect a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

I already read that but it does not fit what I need, since it does not matter if it is an Android or IOS mobile device or if it is a mobile device or not what I want to know is if it is simply a Tablet.
Is there currently something to verify?

Comment: I think this covers your question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195587/2777590

Comment: Great thanks really that was helpful