# Detect device (mobile vs. tablet vs. PC) from browser / user agent data in R

Tags: r, browser, device, user-agent, detect

I am working with log data from a website and I have one variable indicating the browser, e.g.,

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36
```

for PC

or

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
```

for Mobile.

I know that for Python there is a [library](https://pypi.org/project/user-agents/) to do this, is there an equivalent solution for R?

I tried the [uaparserjs package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uaparserjs/uaparserjs.pdf) and it gives out things like device family, device brand etc, but how can I create a variable indicating the device in the categories PC, Mobile, or Tablet?

```
library(uaparserjs)
ua_parse("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; HRY-LX1T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.105 Mobile Safari/537.36")

# A tibble: 1 x 10
  userAgent                                       ua.family  ua.major ua.minor ua.patch os.family os.major device.family device.brand  device.model
  <chr>                                           <chr>      <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>         <chr>         <chr>       
1 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; HRY-LX1T) Appl~ Chrome Mo~ 89       0        4389     Android   10       HRY-LX1T      Generic_Andr~ HRY-LX1T
```

Ideally, I would be able to detect PC vs. mobile vs. tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating PC from mobile/tablet is easy: just use the "os.family" column from `ua_parse`.

But to differentiate mobile and tablet precisely, you would need some screen info (physical size, resolution, density...)
[Detect phone vs tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533106/detect-phone-vs-tablet)

Comment: Thanks. Would you just use an ifelse statement and manually assign the os.family to the device? Something like

device <- ifelse(os.family == "Anroid" | "iOS", "mobile", "desktop") ?

I was wondering if there is no package to directly retrieve the device from the user agent / browser information.

Comment: I would use a `dplyr::case_when`. But, yes, it's similar to doing it with many `if_else`.